# UI client for command line ssh remote server manager

Tags: user-interface, command-line, ssh, client

I learning to use the command line for remote server operation, since the usual ftp/sftp client are terribly slower the unix commands via ssh. But of course is not very practical if you're not an expert.

My question is: does it exist a app (or a webapp) that gives a UI to unix ssh remote commands? something that when for example I copy a file between two folder will use the cp command (wishfully giving you the options).

thanks

PS: I use Mac

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a GUI for the shell, but nice for filesystem operations: [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). Here is a short introduction into sshfs and MacFuse:

- http://zanshin.net/2009/11/06/using-sshfs-macfuse-and-macfusion-to-access-remote-filesystems/

Comment: Ehm, I had some problem with it, it says the authentication failed, but I double and triple check and the password is good. I put as a host "sism.org", is it the right way to write it?

Comment: Not sure about your problem. Without a lengthy reasoning: Try open you *Terminal* application, type `ssh username@host`, where username is your username and host is the remote host (e.g. `sism.org`). Then you should be prompted something along the lines: `The authenticity of host example (134.12.4.48) can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is 9e:1a:5e:27:16:4d:2a:13:90:2c:64:41:bd:25:fd:35. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`. Then type `yes`. Then you should be logged in. You can immediately log out via `exit`. MacFuse should behave differently, then.